# Anylogic update table programmatically before each simulation run

Tags: java, anylogic

In my anylogic model my agents receive their parameters from a database table which is based on an Excel file (this is the part that works).
In the Excel file, each cell has its own code stored, so each time I open the file, the cell values change.

I would like that with each automatic run of my model the Excel file is read in again (i.e. the parameter values of the agents change).
For this I have entered in the experiment under "before each run":

```
Database myFile = new Database(this, "rohdaten2", "C:\Users\2nd User\Models\TestModel_Excel-Pt3_DatabasisForSimulationChanges1\02 DataBasis_Changing_w7oMakros.xlsx");  
rohdaten.importFromExternalDB(myFile.getConnection(), "Rohdaten", "rohdaten", true, false);
```

Unfortunately, I now get the error:

> Description: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r " ' \ ). Location: TestModel_Excel-Pt3_DatabasisForSimulationChanges1/ParametersVariation - Parameter Variation Experiment

The error is due to the specification of the file location, but according to the Anylogic [help](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/import.html) you are supposed to do it this way.
My programming skills generally, but also in Java, are not good enough for me to know what to do now or how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double backslashes instead of single. Backslash in Java is a special character, so you can't use it by its-self. Double backslashes in Java strings are converted to a single backslash.

Your code would look like:

```
Database myFile = new Database(this, "rohdaten2", "C:\\Users\\2nd User\\Models\\TestModel_Excel-Pt3_DatabasisForSimulationChanges1\\02 DataBasis_Changing_w7oMakros.xlsx");
```

Here's an article on escaping characters in Java.
https://codegym.cc/groups/posts/escaping-characters-java